# static analysis for Databricks notebooks

Tags: azure, azure-devops, databricks, azure-databricks

We are using Databricks notebook with and Github as version Control.  I am trying to do static analysis as either part of Github checks or as part of the Azure pipeline.

I am aware of linters available for Python and Scala. however, the challenge here is that one notebook could have Python, Scala, or a SQL code as well.

Using an linter might now work, so is there any way I could achieve this?

Comment: And the actual question is? (and remember, it does not work , or how should I do this is not a good question)

Comment: question is, I am not sure how to achieve this, i am not able to find any linter for databricks. and a single liter won't work.